# image path return null for below android M(6.0) but working for Marshmallow n above

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a bitmap of image and want to save it in internal storage for getting URI of image,

```
getImageUri(Bitmap inImage){
  String path =  MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getApplicationContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", ""); 

  return path;
}
```

its working fine for M(6.0+) versions fine but return null for version lollipop or below. whats wrong with the code? please help me to resolve it.